# Problems reading http get var from url in mvc 3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code that creates an url

```
<a href="ContactInformation/CreateContactInformation/dossierId=@Model.DossierId" class="ContactInformationEdit">Add New</a>
```

(I couldnt find out how to make an actionlink that used an action, controller, object and where I could put a classname on for use in javascript)

That gives a link like this `http://localhost:51730/ContactInformation/CreateContactInformation/dossierId=1`

I then have a controller action

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateContactInformation(int? dossierId)
    {
        return PartialView("ContactInformationCreate", new ContactInformationViewModel(dossierId.Value));
    }
```

But if I put a breakpoint in that code then the variable is just "null" doing a request param gives same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="ContactInformation/CreateContactInformation/?dossierId=@Model.DossierId" class="ContactInformationEdit">Add New</a>
```

i.e. You missed the ? before your query string

Comment: Ha.  Easy mistake.  We all make them.

Answer (score 2):

```
ContactInformation/CreateContactInformation/dossierId=@Model.DossierId
```

Should be

```
ContactInformation/CreateContactInformation?dossierId=@Model.DossierId
```

[Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) helper is used to generate only link. And you could use that link in whatever you like, anchor or anything else. But there also is builtin [ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) overload to generate exactly what you want.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add New", "CreateContactInformation", "ContactInformation", new {dossierId = @Model.DossierId}, new {@class="ContactInformationEdit"})
```

Code above will regard your route configuration too

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the routing right?

```
routes.MapRoute( _
"ContactInformation" _
"ContactInformation/CreateContactInformation/{parameters}" _
new With { .controller = "ContactInformation", .action = "CreateContactInformation"})
```

And then

```
<a href="ContactInformation/CreateContactInformation?dossierId=@Model.DossierId" class="ContactInformationEdit">Add New</a>
```

Comment: And also, sorry for the VB.NET syntax on routing